# how to change the password display character?

Tags: html, usability, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query about Html <input type="password> tag…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430200/query-about-html-input-type-password-tag)

I want change the character displayed in password field

```
password = *********
```

into

```
password = ########
```

Can you please tell me how to set that character in the text box of HTML page with out using any javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without using JavaScript, it's impossible.

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript then please?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt You could use a normal input and on input save to a variable what was entered but visually replace the input with whatever character you want. I would recommend against it though.